# Split String Function in C

Tags: c, string

I am trying to create a function in C that divides a string based on two spaces:

```
char *string = "10234540234  the";
```

I want get_weight() to return

```
10234540234
```

Here is how my function is defined

```
long get_weight(char *string) {
    long length = strlen(string);
    printf("%c \n", string[11]);
    char *number[200];
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (string[i] == " " && string[i+1] == " ") {
            break;
        } else {
            number[count] = string[i];
            count++;
        }
    }
    return atol(number);
}
```

It goes into an infinite loop, and I am not sure why...

Comment: Try to add a `\0` at the end of `number`

Comment: Fyi, `return atol(number);` should be flagging a compiler warning. The function requires `const char *`, you're passing anything-but.

Comment: You do realize just `atol("123  xyz")` would also return 123?

Comment: You would get the same result with `long get_weight(char *string) { return atol(string); }`. because `atoi` will stop at the first wrong character. For better error checking I suggest to use `strtol` instead of `atol`.

Comment: Why not use `sscanf`?

Comment: Why are the two spaces relevant?  What should happen if the number is followed by only one space, or a tab, or a non-digit of any kind?  The simplest approach would be to use `strtol` to extract the number and then check if what comes after the number is acceptable.

Comment: <string.h>'s [strstr](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/functions/strstr.html)(string, "  ") and setting it to '\0' would be much more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were several issues in your code

- Comparison of `string[i]` must be with a character
- `char number[200];` and not `char *number[200];`
- Terminaison of the new string with `'\0'`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

long get_weight(char *string) {
    long length = strlen(string);
    char number[200];
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (string[i] == ' ' && string[i+1] == ' ') {
            break;
        } else {
            number[count] = string[i];
            count++;
        }
    }
    number[count] = '\0';
    return atol(number);
}

int main() {
    char str[] = "12346  abc";
    long num = get_weight (str);
    printf ("number = %ld\n", num);
}
```

Note that as mentioned in comments, if the goal is only to get the leading number, and not to split the input string as the title suggests, you could have only used

```
return atol(string);
```